# Awesome symbols and characters in a bash prompt

Tags: bash, prompt, unicode

I just ran across a screenshot of someone's terminal:

[image: Screenshot of a session showing a prompt with an asterisk and arrow]

Is there a list of all of the characters which can be used in a Bash prompt, or can someone get me the character for the star and the right arrow?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can use any printable character, bash doesn't mind. You'll probably want to configure your terminal to support [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) (in the form of [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)).

There are a lot of characters in Unicode, so here are a few tips to help you search through the Unicode charts:

- You can try to draw the character on [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/). It tries to recognize a Unicode character in what you draw.
- You can try to figure out which block the character is in. For example, that weird-looking symbol and that star would be in a block of miscellaneous symbols; characters like `Ǫ` and `ı` are latin letters with modifiers; `∉` is a mathematical symbol, and so on.
- You can try to think of a word in the description of the character and look for it in a list of unicode symbol names and descriptions. [Gucharmap](http://live.gnome.org/Gucharmap) or [Kcharselect](http://utils.kde.org/projects/kcharselect/) can help.

P.S. On Shapecatcher, I got [U+2234 THEREFORE](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode_info/8756.html) for `∴`, [U+2192 RIGHTWARDS ARROW](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode_info/8594.html) for `→`, [U+263F MERCURY](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode_info/9791.html) for `☿` and [U+2605 BLACK STAR](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode_info/9733.html) for `★`.

In a bash script, up to bash 4.1, you can write a byte by its code point, but not a character. If you want to avoid non-ASCII characters to make your `.bashrc` resilient to file encoding changes, you'll need to enter the bytes corresponding to these characters in the UTF-8 encoding. You can see the hexidecimal values by running `echo ∴ → ☿ ★ | hexdump -C` in a UTF-8 terminal, e.g. `∴` is encoded by `\xe2\x88\xb4` in UTF-8.

```
if [[ $LC_CTYPE =~ '\.[Uu][Tt][Ff]-?8' ]]; then
  PS1=$'\\[\e[31m\\]\xe2\x88\xb4\\[\e[0m\\]\n\xe2\x86\x92 \xe2\x98\xbf \\~ \\[\e[31m\\]\xe2\x98\x85 $? \\[\e[0m\\]'
fi
```

Since bash 4.2, you can use `\u` followed by 4 hexadecimal digits in a `$'…'` string.

```
  PS1=$'\\[\e[31m\\]\u2234\\[\e[0m\\]\n\u2192 \u263f \\~ \\[\e[31m\\]\u2605 $? \\[\e[0m\\]'
```

Comment: Also, you could do : `PS1=$'\u2234\u2192\u263f\u2605'` feels easier to maintain :-)

Comment: @mat Indeed, thanks (but only since bash 4.2).

Comment: Bach get the calculation for char width wrong for multi byte characters. There is, I think, a way to fix this, but I can not remember.

Comment: I have `bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`, and `locale` shows `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`, but when I want to print `\uxxxx` in PS1 string, I got username as output and the unicode character is not recognized...

Comment: @FaithReaper The `\uNNNN` syntax is a feature of `$'…'` quoting, not of prompt expansion. The value of `PS1` must contain the Unicode character. `$'\u1234'` is a way to put the Unicode character into a string.

Comment: That's clear to me now, so I must quote `\uXXXX` with `$' '`.... that's why. Thx!

Answer (score 15):

You can find the unicode symbols on lots of sites, like this one:
http://panmental.de/symbols/info.htm

You just have to make sure that your [term supports UTF-8](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html).

Comment: How would I escape one of these characters? Ie `\u27A4`

Comment: See @Gilles answer, or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash

Comment: You can see all 65000+ unicode points at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ (In the context of code point values "utf8" is synonymous with "unicode".)

Answer (score 4):

i like using these tools — they have a nice experience, and it's easy to search through:

- [unicode character table](https://unicode-table.com/en/)
- [amp-what](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/), scoped to unicode characters