# Is it possible to get a star symbol in Linux?

Tags: terminal, special-characters

Is it possible to get this star symbol in Linux, as shown in this screen shot?

[image]

Comment: yes it certainly is possible.  i've seen it with my own eyes.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`, `zsh`:

```
$ printf '%b\n' '\U2605'
★
```

(Your terminal must support UTF-8 characters)

Comment: cuonglm: this question is answered in this link `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/awesome-symbols-and-characters-in-a-bash-prompt`